# using convolutional neural network for a regression task

Tags: conv-neural-network, keras

I am trying to detect bullets in a shooting target using convolutional neural networks.
The image is a standard shooting target.

The dataset consists of 9216 images of size 96x96 and there is only one bullet somewhere in the image. I labeled each image with the (x,y) of the center of the bullet hole. I also normalized the images.

The model looks like this:

```
 model = Sequential()
 model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, 
                    input_shape=(3,96, 96)))
 model.add(Activation('relu'))
 model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
 model.add(Convolution2D(64, 2, 2))
 model.add(Activation('relu'))
 model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
 model.add(Convolution2D(128, 2, 2))
 model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
 model.add(Flatten())
 model.add(Dense(2))
 model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='rmsprop')
```

The model always converges around the center of the image..

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You are pooling after each convolutional layer. I don't think that would allow it to learn any reasonable features especially near the input. From some models I have seen, it would be better to have some convolutional layers at the beginning before you do any pooling operation.